# Magento: Delete products and 301 redirect to relevant existing page, e.g., it's parent category

Tags: magento

Anyone have a solution for 301 permanent redirects for deleted products in Magento?

I have a store with 5000 products. 4000 have been sold and will never be back in stock. I want to delete those products b/c I no longer need them and want to clean up/decrease my database, but I need to 301 permanently redirect them to appropriate pages to keep the SEO juice I've built up.

To be clear, I do not want the deleted product pages to be live any more, not even with an Out of Stock message, and I do not want 404 Page Not Founds.

Ideally, I would be able to export the product URL and its lowest-level category page's URL so that I could create 301 redirects via an .htaccess file. But exporting from Magento only exports category IDs, not category names or URLs, so how do I get these programmaticly? Or other solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

I would create a plugin that leverages observers and Magento's URL Rewrite Manager.

This plugin would observe the `catalog_controller_product_delete` event which returns `array(’product’ ⇒ $product)` to the Observer's `$event` var upon product delete - this would create automatic redirects upon deletion.

You can use this to get last-minute details about the product, including its url, and then do the following to insert into the url rewrite:

```
Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')
    ->setIsSystem(0)
    ->setStoreId($storeId)   
    ->setOptions('RP')  //301 redirect perm
    ->setTargetPath($product->getUrlPath() . '.html')
    ->setRequestPath($newpage->getUrlPath() . '.html')
    ->save();
```

Comment: Sounds like a good technique to create a rewrite just before deleting. But how do we get the products' category URL for the rewrites?

Answer (score 1):

The following solution will only work if your products have only 1 category.
This code will work deleting at admin product grid and admin product view.

This code will make a redirect to the category the product is in. Except if that category has no products after deleting, it will use the parent category of the product category instead. This creates a problem because many of the rewrites will still link to a category without products.
If this is not a problem for you use the following solution.

In ./app/code/local/INPUTANAME/RewriteAfterDelete/etc/config.xml put

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <INPUTANAME_RewriteAfterDelete>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </INPUTANAME_RewriteAfterDelete>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <inputaname_rewriteafterdelete>
                <class>INPUTANAME_RewriteAfterDelete_Model</class>
            </inputaname_rewriteafterdelete>
        </models>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_delete_after>
                <observers>
                    <inputaname_rewriteafterdelete>
                        <class>inputaname_rewriteafterdelete/observer</class>
                        <method>rewriteDelete</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </inputaname_rewriteafterdelete>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_delete_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

In ./app/code/local/INPUTANAME/RewriteAfterDelete/Model/Observer.php

```
    <?php
class BeoService_RewriteAfterDelete_Model_Observer
{
    public function rewriteDelete(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
        $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
        if(count($categoryIds) ){
            $firstCategoryId = $categoryIds[0];
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($firstCategoryId);
            if($category->getProductCount()){
                $newpage = $category->getUrlPath();
            }else{
                $newpage = $category->getParentCategory()->getUrlPath();
            }
            Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')
                ->setIsSystem(0)
                ->setStoreId($storeId)   
                ->setOptions('RP')  //301 redirect perm
                ->setTargetPath($newpage . '.html')
                ->setRequestPath($product->getUrlPath() . '.html')
                ->save(); 
        }
    }
}
```

In ./app/etc/modules/INPUTANAME_RewriteAfterDelete.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <INPUTANAME_RewriteAfterDelete>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </INPUTANAME_RewriteAfterDelete>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <inputaname_rewriteafterdelete>
                <class>INPUTANAME_RewriteAfterDelete_Model</class>
            </inputaname_rewriteafterdelete>
        </models>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_delete_after>
                <observers>
                    <inputaname_rewriteafterdelete>
                        <class>inputaname_rewriteafterdelete/observer</class>
                        <method>rewriteDelete</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </inputaname_rewriteafterdelete>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_delete_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the data you want, you can simply run this query

```
SELECT prod.request_path, cat.request_path FROM `core_url_rewrite` prod
LEFT JOIN core_url_rewrite cat ON prod.category_id = cat.category_id AND cat.id_path LIKE 'category/%'
WHERE prod.id_path LIKE 'product/%' AND prod.category_id IS NOT NULL
```

Beware adding a lot of static redirects to .htaccess will slowdown apache.

Answer (score 0):

Using this you can only redirect Active Category this functionality is remain to all answer.Hope so any one can help full this.

```
<?php
class Meet_RewriteAfterDelete_Model_Observer
{
    public function rewriteDelete(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
        $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
        if(count($categoryIds) ){
            $categoryIds = $this->getActiveCategoryIds($categoryIds);
        }
        $requestPath = '';
        if($product->getUrlPath() != ""){
            $requestPath = $product->getUrlPath();
        }else{
            $requestPath = $product->getUrlKey();
        }
        if(count($categoryIds) ){
            $firstCategoryId = $categoryIds[0];
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($firstCategoryId);
            if($category->getProductCount()){
                $newpage = $category->getUrlPath();
            }else{
                $newpage = $category->getParentCategory()->getUrlPath();
            }
            Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')
                ->setIsSystem(0)
                ->setStoreId($storeId)   
                ->setOptions('RP') 
                ->setTargetPath($newpage)
                ->setIdPath(uniqid(delete_))
                ->setRequestPath($requestPath)
                ->save(); 
        }else{
            Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')
                ->setIsSystem(0)
                ->setStoreId($storeId)   
                ->setOptions('RP') 
                ->setTargetPath('index.php')
                ->setIdPath(uniqid(delete_))
                ->setRequestPath($requestPath)
                ->save(); 
        }
    }

    protected function getActiveCategoryIds($catIds){
        $catCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
             ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
             ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $catIds)
             ->addIsActiveFilter();
        return $catCollection->getAllIds();
    }

}
```